# Searching for users using Graph API with Application access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search for users( by their names or usernames) using Graph API. 
I have an access token as an application.
Can I user an App access token to search users?
The results that I need are like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=xxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

I tried that with an app access token and the error was

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 102
  }
}
```

So no, you must use a user access token to search for users